# How to get debug an app online in android

Tags: android, performance, debugging

Hi i am trying to build an voip app.the issue is app is working fine in our test environments but in our client mobile devices it doesn't.how can i enable logs online or get my apps logs .is there any tools.how can i do it to see what happens in my app currently in client device. 
My app is not getting crashed and i am using firebase for getting crash reports.so what i require is how can i enable my app log and get it to me.

Comment: you can't get the logs whenever you want. But using third party providers you will get the LOG's while application crash. firebase crashlytics, fabric crashlytics etc useful to track user logs.

Comment: @sunil yes man im using firebase for getting crash reports but i need to get apps logs is there some tools or ideas

Comment: I suggest that you ask one of the clients to cooperate and use a tool like `TeamViewer` to connect to the client's computer and see the logs in his/her logcat. Or ask one of them to run the app and send you what thy see in logcat.

Comment: @Merka yup dats the idea i suggested to my project manager he doesnt agree with dat bro

Comment: @Merka i thought this was a common problem so everyone mayb using tool seems now strange to be

Comment: @Jeeva nope, if it happens on specific device, you can ask for all specifications (device model and brand, os version, locale, etc) of the device from the user and try to test on a similar device to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this library: [ACRA library](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), It will show a dialog when your app have been crashed, the user can send error log to your team.

Comment: bro im using firebase for getting crashreports and it is working good i need to analyse excatly what is happening in my app right now so is there  any library which can help me get the logs